# Does the lock extend to the joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have got two following queries (note, table `books` has foreign key `author_id` to the table `authors`):

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE books.author_id = 1
FOR UPDATE
```

```
SELECT * FROM authors
JOIN books ON books.author_id = authors.id
WHERE authors.id = 1
```

Will the first query block the second one making the second query wait for the first one to finish? We are locking `books` record with `author_id = 1` but does this lock extend to the other queries that join `books`?

Comment: From the  [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html):  *If FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE is specified, the SELECT statement locks the selected rows against concurrent updates.*   Since your second SELECT is not a concurrent update, the second SELECT is not blocked.  Why not try executing these SQL statements and see for yourself.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Does it mean that if I add to the second query `FOR UPDATE`, then it will wait for the first query to finish (taking into account the second query joins locked record)?

Comment: No, because in the first SQL, you're locking book rows.  In the second SQL, you're locking author rows.  By the way, table names should be singular.  It's less confusing.  Finally, your FOR UPDATE and your actual UPDATE should be as close together as possible to keep the lock for the minimum amount of time.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc good clarification, thank you. Post your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc. "By the way, table names should be singular." That is your convention. A good one but **not** universal. Look at Information_Schema and see how Postgres names theirs.  I myself always use plural table name as I find that less confusing. Just a different way of looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my answer that absolutely depends on the comment by @GilbertLeBlanc (big thanks for a good clarification).

From the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html): If FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE is specified, the SELECT statement locks the selected rows against concurrent updates. Since my second SELECT is not a concurrent update, the second SELECT is not blocked.

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE books.author_id = 1
FOR UPDATE
```

```
SELECT * FROM authors
JOIN books ON books.author_id = authors.id
WHERE authors.id = 1
```

For the above queries, the second one won't be blocked although first query locked the record but the second query does not do `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. Even if we add `FOR UPDATE` for the second query - it won't be blocked by the first query because the first one locks `books` record whereas the second one would block `authors` record.

To sum it up: If you do lock for update, concurrent selects that are not used for concurrent updates won't be blocked. The lock extends to a join and a query with a join is blocked if the query that uses the join tries to lock (FOR UPDATE, FOR SHARE) the record that is already locked by any other queries. But if the query with a join does not want to lock the record from the joining table - blocking does not happen.

If anyone has anything else to add - feel free to correct me here.